# Namenode not starting - Exception in namenode join

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

my namenode is not starting up.

Tried formatting and deleting tmp directory before attempting a restart. but it doesn't come up.

Currently i am attemting for a two node cluster. I cloned both nodes from a single node machine. And changed properties to resemble one for name node, job tracker and secondary name node. And the other for the rest.

On trying to start the name node. I am getting below exception in logs. Tried searching, but didn't find anything specific to my problem. Also i have set up password less ssh, in case any permissions are denied beacause of that.

```
2015-08-08 12:40:59,005 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG: 
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = HNNAME/192.168.136.170
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 2.0.0-cdh4.7.0
STARTUP_MSG:   classpath = /etc/hadoop/conf:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-math-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/zookeeper-3.4.5-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/kfs-0.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/cloudera-jets3t-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jetty-6.1.26.cloudera.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/junit-4.8.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jets3t-0.6.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.cloudera.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-net-3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jackson-xc-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jersey-json-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-column-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0-sources.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-hive-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0-sources.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-column-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-scrooge-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0-sources.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-common-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0-tests.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-hadoop-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0-sources.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-generator-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0-javadoc.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-auth.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-pig-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0-javadoc.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-annotations-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-common-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-generator-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0-sources.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-avro-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-cascading-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0-javadoc.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-thrift-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0-javadoc.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-thrift-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0-sources.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-generator-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-cascading-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-common-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0-sources.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-avro-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0-sources.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-avro-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0-javadoc.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-cascading-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0-sources.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-encoding-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-pig-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0-sources.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-thrift-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-common-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0-javadoc.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-hive-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-auth-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-pig-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-encoding-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0-javadoc.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-hive-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0-javadoc.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-format-1.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-common-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-format-1.0.0-cdh4.7.0-sources.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-annotations.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-test-hadoop2-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-hadoop-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0-javadoc.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-encoding-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0-sources.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-common.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-hadoop-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-scrooge-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-column-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0-javadoc.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-scrooge-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0-javadoc.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-pig-bundle-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0-sources.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-pig-bundle-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-format-1.0.0-cdh4.7.0-javadoc.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/./:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/zookeeper-3.4.5-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jetty-6.1.26.cloudera.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-daemon-1.0.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.cloudera.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/.//hadoop-hdfs-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0-tests.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/.//hadoop-hdfs-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/.//hadoop-hdfs.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/netty-3.2.4.Final.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/jersey-guice-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-applications-unmanaged-am-launcher-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-common.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-api.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-tests-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0-tests.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-common.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-client-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-applications-unmanaged-am-launcher.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-tests-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-site.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-api-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-client.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-common-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-tests.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-site-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/netty-3.2.4.Final.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/jersey-guice-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-archives-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-datajoin.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-distcp-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-streaming-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-core.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-rumen-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-plugins.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-extras-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-datajoin-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-rumen.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-app.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-common.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-streaming.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-gridmix-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-extras.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0-tests.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-archives.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-distcp.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-gridmix.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-plugins-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar
STARTUP_MSG:   build = git://centos32-6-slave.sf.cloudera.com/data/1/jenkins/workspace/generic-package-centos32-6/topdir/BUILD/hadoop-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0/src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common -r 8e266e052e423af592871e2dfe09d54c03f6a0e8; compiled by 'jenkins' on Wed May 28 10:12:25 PDT 2014
STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.6.0_45
************************************************************/
2015-08-08 12:40:59,010 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
2015-08-08 12:40:59,576 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2015-08-08 12:40:59,718 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2015-08-08 12:40:59,718 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system started
2015-08-08 12:41:00,059 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Util: Path /storage/name should be specified as a URI in configuration files. Please update hdfs configuration.
2015-08-08 12:41:00,060 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Util: Path /storage/name should be specified as a URI in configuration files. Please update hdfs configuration.
2015-08-08 12:41:00,061 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Only one image storage directory (dfs.namenode.name.dir) configured. Beware of dataloss due to lack of redundant storage directories!
2015-08-08 12:41:00,061 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Only one namespace edits storage directory (dfs.namenode.edits.dir) configured. Beware of dataloss due to lack of redundant storage directories!
2015-08-08 12:41:00,069 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Util: Path /storage/name should be specified as a URI in configuration files. Please update hdfs configuration.
2015-08-08 12:41:00,069 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Util: Path /storage/name should be specified as a URI in configuration files. Please update hdfs configuration.
2015-08-08 12:41:00,101 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: fsLock is fair:true
2015-08-08 12:41:00,165 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.HeartbeatManager: Setting heartbeat recheck interval to 30000 since dfs.namenode.stale.datanode.interval is less than dfs.namenode.heartbeat.recheck-interval
2015-08-08 12:41:00,180 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.DatanodeManager: dfs.block.invalidate.limit=1000
2015-08-08 12:41:00,187 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: Computing capacity for map BlocksMap
2015-08-08 12:41:00,187 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: VM type       = 32-bit
2015-08-08 12:41:00,196 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: 2.0% max memory 966.7 MB = 19.3 MB
2015-08-08 12:41:00,196 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: capacity      = 2^22 = 4194304 entries
2015-08-08 12:41:01,099 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: dfs.block.access.token.enable=false
2015-08-08 12:41:01,100 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: defaultReplication         = 1
2015-08-08 12:41:01,100 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxReplication             = 512
2015-08-08 12:41:01,100 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: minReplication             = 1
2015-08-08 12:41:01,100 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxReplicationStreams      = 2
2015-08-08 12:41:01,100 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: shouldCheckForEnoughRacks  = false
2015-08-08 12:41:01,100 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: replicationRecheckInterval = 3000
2015-08-08 12:41:01,100 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: encryptDataTransfer        = false
2015-08-08 12:41:01,100 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxNumBlocksToLog          = 1000
2015-08-08 12:41:01,110 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: fsOwner             = hdfs (auth:SIMPLE)
2015-08-08 12:41:01,110 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: supergroup          = supergroup
2015-08-08 12:41:01,111 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: isPermissionEnabled = false
2015-08-08 12:41:01,111 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: HA Enabled: false
2015-08-08 12:41:01,115 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Append Enabled: true
2015-08-08 12:41:01,547 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Caching file names occuring more than 10 times
2015-08-08 12:41:01,549 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.threshold-pct = 0.9990000128746033
2015-08-08 12:41:01,549 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.min.datanodes = 0
2015-08-08 12:41:01,549 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.extension     = 30000
2015-08-08 12:41:01,562 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Lock on /storage/name/in_use.lock acquired by nodename 7800@HNNAME
2015-08-08 12:41:01,640 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FileJournalManager: Recovering unfinalized segments in /storage/name/current
2015-08-08 12:41:01,772 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage: Loading image file /storage/name/current/fsimage_0000000000000038306 using no compression
2015-08-08 12:41:01,772 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage: Number of files = 4012
2015-08-08 12:41:01,932 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage: Number of files under construction = 1
2015-08-08 12:41:01,941 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage: Image file of size 343797 loaded in 0 seconds.
2015-08-08 12:41:01,941 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage: Loaded image for txid 38306 from /storage/name/current/fsimage_0000000000000038306
2015-08-08 12:41:01,944 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage: Reading org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.RedundantEditLogInputStream@c623af expecting start txid #38307
2015-08-08 12:41:01,965 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.EditLogInputStream: Fast-forwarding stream '/storage/name/current/edits_0000000000000038307-0000000000000038308' to transaction ID 38307
2015-08-08 12:41:01,985 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage: Edits file /storage/name/current/edits_0000000000000038307-0000000000000038308 of size 30 edits # 2 loaded in 0 seconds
2015-08-08 12:41:02,045 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: Starting log segment at 38309
2015-08-08 12:41:02,154 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FileJournalManager: Unable to start log segment 38309 at /storage/name/current/edits_inprogress_0000000000000038309: /storage/name/current/edits_inprogress_0000000000000038309 (Permission denied)
2015-08-08 12:41:02,154 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage: Error reported on storage directory Storage Directory /storage/name
2015-08-08 12:41:02,154 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage: About to remove corresponding storage: /storage/name
2015-08-08 12:41:02,155 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: Error: starting log segment 38309 failed for (journal JournalAndStream(mgr=FileJournalManager(root=/storage/name), stream=null))
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/name/current/edits_inprogress_0000000000000038309 (Permission denied)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:216)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.EditLogFileOutputStream.<init>(EditLogFileOutputStream.java:74)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FileJournalManager.startLogSegment(FileJournalManager.java:105)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.JournalSet$JournalAndStream.startLogSegment(JournalSet.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.JournalSet$2.apply(JournalSet.java:197)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.JournalSet.mapJournalsAndReportErrors(JournalSet.java:347)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.JournalSet.startLogSegment(JournalSet.java:194)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog.startLogSegment(FSEditLog.java:923)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog.openForWrite(FSEditLog.java:264)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.openEditLogForWrite(FSImage.java:574)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFSImage(FSNamesystem.java:747)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFromDisk(FSNamesystem.java:531)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.loadNamesystem(NameNode.java:403)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:445)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:621)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1177)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1241)
2015-08-08 12:41:02,156 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: Disabling journal JournalAndStream(mgr=FileJournalManager(root=/storage/name), stream=null)
2015-08-08 12:41:02,156 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: Error: starting log segment 38309 failed for too many journals
2015-08-08 12:41:02,157 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Stopping NameNode metrics system...
2015-08-08 12:41:02,157 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system stopped.
2015-08-08 12:41:02,158 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system shutdown complete.
2015-08-08 12:41:02,158 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Exception in namenode join
java.io.IOException: Unable to start log segment 38309: too few journals successfully started.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog.startLogSegment(FSEditLog.java:925)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog.openForWrite(FSEditLog.java:264)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.openEditLogForWrite(FSImage.java:574)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFSImage(FSNamesystem.java:747)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFromDisk(FSNamesystem.java:531)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.loadNamesystem(NameNode.java:403)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:445)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:621)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1177)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1241)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: starting log segment 38309 failed for too many journals
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.JournalSet.mapJournalsAndReportErrors(JournalSet.java:374)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.JournalSet.startLogSegment(JournalSet.java:194)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog.startLogSegment(FSEditLog.java:923)
    ... 10 more
2015-08-08 12:41:02,159 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
2015-08-08 12:41:02,160 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at HNNAME/192.168.136.170
************************************************************/
```

Comment: does the user running namenode have have write permissions to the tmp folder ? could you also post your config files ?

Comment: yeah. i am using root and it does have permissions on tmp  drwxrwxrwx. 4 hdfs hadoop    4096 Aug  8 13:13 tmp

Comment: CORE-SITE.xml  <configuration>
<property>

<name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>

<value>/usr/lib/hadoop/tmp</value>

</property>

<property>

<name>fs.default.name</name>

<value>hdfs://HNNAME:8020</value>

</property>
</configuration>

Comment: MAPRED-SITE.xml *<configuration>
<property>

<name>mapred.job.tracker</name>

<value>hdfs://HNNAME:8021</value>

</property>

<property>

<name>mapred.system.dir</name>

<value>/mapred/system</value>

</property>

<property>

<name>mapred.local.dir</name>

<value>/mapred/local</value>

</property>

<property>

<name>mapred.temp.dir</name>

<value>/mapred/temp</value>

</property>
</configuration>*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not giving the permissions for the namenode meta-data location correctly. To make sure it works correctly, Verify your procedure following the steps below.

Assuming Namenode meta-data location: `/storage/name`

- `mkdir -p /storage/name`
- `chown -R hdfs:hadoop /storage/name`
- `sudo -u hdfs hadoop namenode -format`
- `service hdfs-namenode start` (assuming cdh rpm installation is used. This varies with the installation method you used)

Hadoop daemon will start as an `hdfs` user, and if the metadata location permissions are not set to hadoop user and hadoop superuser group, you get the error mentioned above.

If you observe the above log generated, FileSystem owner: fsOwner is `hdfs` and super group is `supergroup`. And the Exception is `FileNotFound` because the service responsible to start namenode is unable to access the filesystem, since it does not have required permissions.

Comment: just 5-6 hours of looking for an error before finding YOUR answer :)  thanks a lot!  there's still a lot to be done in understanding all this hadoop/cloudera/hdfs stuff, but you've got me 1 big step further :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in hortonworks after adding another disk to hdfs. I simply did `chown hdfs:hadoop -R /hadoop/hdfs` and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

For my hadoop on Unbutu(WSL), it works by typing in:

```
cd /usr/local/hadoop           # your directory path may be different
./sbin/stop-dfs.sh              # stop
rm -r ./tmp                   # delete tmp folder
./bin/hdfs namenode -format   # reformat NameNode
./sbin/start-dfs.sh            # restart
```

Hope this can help u :)